# How to unzip password protected file via Ruby

Tags: ruby, unzip, rubyzip

I'd like to unzip an encrypted/password protected file via a Ruby script without dropping down to a system call. I currently use the rubyzip library to unzip files but don't see an option for working with encrypted files.

Anyone know of some code or a library that will do this?

Comment: The requirements changed and I don't have to unzip a password protected file anymore so I'm using RubyZip to do the unzip. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is one that works great by the way, I've just tried it and found your post in the middle..

[Archive-zip](https://github.com/javanthropus/archive-zip)

Example of use:

```
require 'archive/zip'
Archive::Zip.extract('example5.zip', 'a_destination', :password => 'seakrit')
```

I'm sure that this will be useful for someone else looking for the same on google :)

Comment: Your answer was useful for somebody searching via google ;) Can be installed via `gem install archive-zip` and worked without problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the right answer is to use a system call. That's why it's there.

True, it's slower and less elegant than using a library or a method. But it's cheaper than paying a tax to someone (a royalty payment) and much much faster than writing a new library yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I've heard of to date is the [**Chilkat Ruby Zip library**](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/), which isn't free. The RubyZip library does not support password-protected files because the underlying library, zlib, doesn't do so either.

Comment: RubyZip supports password protected unzip:
https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/blob/e5e3f97ec891cb596f1af8950fc9749c99b809e9/test/encryption_test.rb

Answer (score 0):

Not a ruby library, but...maybe a free option.

If your app runs on Windows, you can use the [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) library, via the new COM interface. It does password-protected files, either Zip encryption (weak), or WinZip-compatible AES encryption.

DotNetZip is free.

If Windows is out of the question, there may be another possibility.  DotNetZip runs in Mono, too.  I don't know if there are Ruby-to-Mono integration mechanisms to allow you to call from Ruby to Mono on other platforms, but if they exist, they also may let you call into DotNetZip.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the option of using JRuby + a Java library for handling zip files.  http://www.lingala.net/zip4j handles (encrypted) zip files and is Apache licensed.  I've not used it yet, but it *should* work.